# Thread 1 error when trying to update variable SwiftUI Instagram Tutorial

Tags: xcode, variables, swiftui, instagram

I am new to coding and am currently running through an instagram tutorial using SwiftUI and in order to develop my skills I have been tweaking my layouts to try new concepts.

I am currently having an issue with "updating the like count". The tutorial shows  the typical instagram layout of the likeCount variable a part of the "Footer" (under the image) under the like button, but I have gone with the approach (similar to Vero) with having the like button on the Header and like count on the footer.

[image: Instagram layout]

[image: Vero layout]

**See current code:**

```
        import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    import FirebaseAuth

class HeaderCellViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var post: Post!
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var isLiked = false
    
    func checkPostIsLiked() {
        isLiked = (post.likes["\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)"] == true) ? true : false
    }

    func like() {
        post.likeCount += 1
        isLiked = true
        
        Ref.FIRESTORE_MY_POSTS_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: post.ownerId).collection("userPosts").document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : true,
                                                                                    "likeCount": post.likeCount])
        Ref.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_ALL_POSTS.document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : true,
                                                                             "likeCount": post.likeCount])
        Ref.FIRESTORE_TIMELINE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: post.ownerId).collection("timelinePosts").document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : true,
                                                                                        "likeCount": post.likeCount])
    }
    
    func unlike() {
        post.likeCount -= 1
        isLiked = false
        
        Ref.FIRESTORE_MY_POSTS_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: post.ownerId).collection("userPosts").document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : false,
                                                                                    "likeCount": post.likeCount])
        Ref.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_ALL_POSTS.document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : false,
                                                                             "likeCount": post.likeCount])
        Ref.FIRESTORE_TIMELINE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: post.ownerId).collection("timelinePosts").document(post.postId).updateData(["likes.\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)" : false,
                                                                                        "likeCount": post.likeCount])
    }

}


    import SwiftUI
```

---

```
    import SwiftUI
import URLImage

struct HeaderCell: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var headerCellViewModel = HeaderCellViewModel()
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.headerCellViewModel.post = post
        self.headerCellViewModel.checkPostIsLiked()
    }

 if headerCellViewModel.post.likeCount > 0 {
                Text("\(headerCellViewModel.post.likeCount)")
            }
            Image(systemName: (self.headerCellViewModel.isLiked) ? "hand.thumbsup.fill" : "hand.thumbsup").resizable().scaledToFill().frame(width: 30, height: 30).foregroundColor(.gray).onTapGesture {
                if self.headerCellViewModel.isLiked {
                    self.headerCellViewModel.unlike()
                } else {
                    self.headerCellViewModel.like()
                }
            }
```

---

```
struct FooterCell: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var footerCellViewModel = FooterCellViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var headerCellViewModel = HeaderCellViewModel()
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.footerCellViewModel.post = post
        self.footerCellViewModel.checkPostIsLiked()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Text(self.footerCellViewModel.post.caption).font(.subheadline).padding(.leading)
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse").foregroundColor(.gray).imageScale(.small)
                Text("Location").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)
            }.padding(.leading)
            
            HStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CommentView(post: self.footerCellViewModel.post)) {
                    Text("4K")
                    Image(systemName: "text.bubble").renderingMode(.original)
                }
                Spacer().frame(width: 15)
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Likes")) {
                    if footerCellViewModel.post.likeCount > 0 {
                        Text("\(footerCellViewModel.post.likeCount)")
                    } else {
                      Text("0")
                    }
                    
                    Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup").renderingMode(.original)
                }
```

My issue is that when I refer to headerCellViewModel from footerCell it comes up with "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" and crashes. I copied the headerCellViewModel and made it footer but the viewcount doesn't update live when I press the like button now. They're just not talking to eachother and I am unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `post` to header view model as well (because it is explicitly force-unwrapped in declaration, ie `var post: Post!`)

```
struct FooterCell: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var footerCellViewModel = FooterCellViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var headerCellViewModel = HeaderCellViewModel()
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.footerCellViewModel.post = post
        self.headerCellViewModel.post = post    // << here !!
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi for the response! I added it in but it still seems to not be updating on the footercell. Do you know the reasoning why I just can't refer straight to headerCell so i don't have to copy the viewmodels?

Comment: SwiftUI is reactive by nature, you should manipulate with model and view will update automatically if model is changed. If you want header & footer be updated on same changes you have to use same `HeaderCellViewModel` instance, now you create for each view its own - instead create one and pass by arguments it in both views.